# Short put prices different strikes

Tags: options, put

I was looking at Robinhood and can't find a rational reason for a put price for the $\\\$117$ strike to be higher than both the $\\\$116$ and the $\\\$119$ strike.

[image]

Comment: What are the buy prices for these puts?

Comment: On the right. The orange and green values.

Comment: I meant the corresponding values for "Buy Puts"

Comment: They are the same !!!

Comment: Then buy a 120 put at 0.01 and sell a 118 put at 1.05

Comment: Precisely ! Seems to good to be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the bid/ask spread. Alternatively, try to put a trade on and see why it won’t work. That’s what I normally do.